# Parameter mandatory don't apply correctly in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I try to valide a parameter in my function,
i want this one to be here and be an IP.
If not showing me prompt to correct (like normal usage)
But actually it just throwing me error in cmd OUTPUT (no prompt showing) and even the help message is not displayed.
I made something wrong apparantly but don't know what.

here is the code :

```
function Test-IP
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
             HelpMessage = "Enter a valid IP Address")]
        [ValidateScript({ $_ -match [System.Net.IPAddress]$_ })]
        $IP
    )

    Write-Host $IP
}
```

Thanks

Comment: No, this is expected behavior - the prompt is facilitated by the host application, whereas the validation is handled by powershell itself, and so the prompt interface doesn't actually "know" how to validate (and re-prompt the user).

Comment: Note that a better way do do what you're trying here is `Param ([Parameter(Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage = "Enter a valid IP Address")][System.Net.IPAddress]$IP)` to force a parameter to be an IP address.  Alternately, you can ignore the function entirely and use `[ipaddress]::TryParse($IP,[ref][ipaddress]$null)` to test if something is a valid IP Address.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So i can't have a prompt with this usage ? so how people make them work ? i see some give exemple with that prompt, but it don't show when i try their exemples.

Comment: @BaconBits The function don't only do that, the validate IP is just a verification, but thanks for the simplification !

Comment: Can you link to some of these examples?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/22/use-powershell-to-make-mandatory-parameters/) but its from 2011

Comment: Except that example doesn't actually attempt to implement what you describe (re-prompting on validation failure)